# How can a Vue component button color be changed using a function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button

How can a Vue component button color be changed using a function? Bootstrap-vue is being used. In the code below, the tooltip is changed using a function, how can the same idea be applied to the button? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <b-button v-b-tooltip.hover.right="tooltipText" variant="outline-primary" @click="userHandler(username)">
      <div v-bind:class="{ active: checkbox1 }">
        {{ username }}
      </div>
    </b-button>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import EventBus from '../eventBus.js'
export default {

    props: ['username', 'checkbox1'],

    data() {
      return {
         show: true,
         tooltipTextContent: 'block',
     }      
},

methods: {


    userHandler(username) {

        EventBus.$emit('handleUser', username);  
    },


     tooltipText() {
          if (!this.checkbox1) {
            return this.tooltipTextContent
          } else {
            return `un${this.tooltipTextContent}`
          }
    }
},
} 

</script>
<style scoped>

.active {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Object Syntax

If you want to change the colour of the button based on `checkbox1` prop, you can do this like:

```
<b-button 
   v-b-tooltip.hover.right="tooltipText" 
   :variant="{ 'outline-primary': checkbox1, 'outline-secondary': !checkbox1 }" 
   @click="userHandler(username)">
```

This will set button colour to `outline-primary` if `checkbox1` is `true`, else set it to `outline-secondary` colour. You can change the colour and logic based on your requirement.

Also, note that here `:variant` is simply a shortcut for `v-bind:variant`.

### Using Computed Property

We can also bind to a computed property that returns an object. This is a common and powerful pattern:

```
<b-button 
   v-b-tooltip.hover.right="tooltipText" 
   :variant="getVariant" 
   @click="userHandler(username)">
```

and then create a computed property named `getVariant` like:

```
computed: {
  getVariant: function () {
    return {
      'outline-primary': this.checkbox1,
      'outline-secondary': !this.checkbox1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the button color using a function, like what is being done with the toolltip?

Comment: Yes, we can also bind to a computed property that returns an object. This is a common and powerful pattern. I have updated the code.

Comment: Is it possible to change the button color with a regular function inside methods?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Just put the computed prop to methods instead and the call it like `:variant="getVariant()"`